# Only allow a mongo collection to have x documents in it

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using a Mongo collection to have logging functionality. I want it to be a tailing log, so it should only hold 200 entries before tailing the others. The functionality would be similar to `tail -f -n 200`

It's possible to use `limit` in a query to have a similar effect in terms of querying.

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
Posts.find({}, { limit: 200 });
```

But this doesn't delete old entries from the collection. I have no need for the previous entries.

Is there a way to do this with mongodb?

Comment: I was answering to his question, and I realized it might be trickier than it seems. How would you remove all the items older than the 200th?

Comment: So far, the main thing I've been doing is just using a `limit` in the publication, which "works", but is not optimal. It's just ideal to have it not hold more data than it actually needs to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is a capped collection: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/

MDG was friendly enough to include this in the Meteor wrapper, although it's internal.

```
Foo = Mongo.collection('foo');
Foo._createCappedCollection(sizeInBytes, numOfDocs);
```

A great example of a capped collection is the Oplog, which is just a replica of a capped collection. Meteor watches these changes & when something changes that is actionable, it triggers an invalidation. You can find this in Robomongo: `System>local>collections>oplog.rs` and if that provides everything you need, you may not even need to make your own.

Alternatively, there's a bunch of options on npm so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. This article is a bit dated, but worth the read: https://meteorhacks.com/logging-support-for-meteor

Comment: Oh that's cool, I'd never heard of capped collections, especially not in a Meteor context!

Comment: that's excellent! Exactly what I was looking for, thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

Just use [percolate:synced-cron](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron) and write a little cron job that deletes old posts.

```
var nPosts = Posts.find().count();
if ( nPosts > 200 ){
  Posts.remove({},{sort: {createdAt: 1}, limit: ( nPosts - 200 )});
}
```

Alternatively you could use [mat33:collection-hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) and do this pruning after every insert.